# Regarding destructor in an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a question regarding how the destructor is called. For example, I created the following foo class and supplied with copy constructor, destructor and overloaded the assignment operator. I created a dynamic array of this foo objects and used the operator "=" to assign individual element of the array. I am very confused, immediately after the assignment operation, the destructor is called and when I want to access the data in the newly assigned object, I got very confusing result.Any suggestions?

[image]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool debug = true;

class foo{
private:
    int n;


    void init(int _n);
public:

    int* arr; // just to make it accessible so that we can tract the contents;

    foo(int _n);
    foo(int* _a, int len);
    foo(const foo & rhs);
    foo & operator=(const foo & rhs);
    ~foo();
};


void foo::init(int _n = 0){
    n = _n;
    arr = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i != n; i++) arr[i] = 0;
}

foo::foo(int _n = 0){
    init(_n);
}

foo::foo(int*_a, int len){
    init(len);
    for(int i = 0; i< len; i++) arr[i] = _a[i];
}

foo::foo(const foo &rhs){
    operator = (rhs);
}

 foo& foo::operator= (const foo &rhs){
     if(debug) cout<<"\nassignment operator overloaded";
     if (this != &rhs){
         if(n != 0) {
            n = rhs.n;
            delete [] arr;
            arr = new int[n];
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = rhs.arr[i];
         }
     }
     return *this;
}

foo::~foo(){
    if (debug)cout << "\ndestructor called\n";
    delete []arr;
}

int main(){

    { // a explicit block to see when the destructor is called;
        foo* f = new foo[4];
        int n = 4;
        int a[] = {0,1,2,3};
        for(int i = 0; i < n;i++) {
            cout<<i;
            f[i] = foo(a, i);
            cout<<f[i].arr[i]<<"\n"; // result is some seemingly random number;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}*
```

Comment: I've fixed the deconstructor usage so this is googleable

Comment: \after the construction of an object it should be ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
f[i] = foo(a, i);
```

a temporary `foo` object is created on the RHS of the assignment operator. It is then used to assign to the `foo` on the LHS of the operator. Then, it is destroyed, therefore its destructor is called.

The reason for the garbage values after the assignments is probably that `n` is `0` in all the `foos` in the array. Your assignment operator is broken. You may want to have a look at the [*copy and swap idiom*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Answer (score 1):

A big no no! Delegating initialization of an uninitialized object to the assignment operator is a no good idea:

```
foo::foo(const foo &rhs){
    operator = (rhs);
}
```

Better is:

```
foo::foo(const foo &rhs)
:   n(rhs.n), arr(new int[n])
{
    // copy rhs.arr to arr
}

// Note: Passing by value:
foo& operator = (foo rhs) {
   std::swap(n, rhs.n);
   std::swap(arr, rhs.arr);
   return *this;
   // Note: The swapped rhs will do the cleanup in the destructor
}
```

You will end up with less coding and exception safety

Another issue is:

> cout << f[i].arr[i] << "\n"

You are printing an undefined 'end' value (arr[i] == arr[n])

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I tried to modify my code according to your suggestion, I still got the similar wired numbers. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @XuanZhou another issue is 'cout<<f[i].arr[i]<<"\n"'- you are printing an undefined 'end' value (arr[i] == arr[n])

Comment: thanks, I see. If only I could think it through in the begining